# Grabbing object value from last index in nested array

Tags: javascript

I am making a recipe app with react and am incorperating a button to load more results at the bottom of the page. I have a data structure that looks like:

```js
const data = [
  [_links: {...}, hits:{...}],
  [_links: {...}, hits:{...}],
  [
    _links: {
      next: {
        title: "Next",
        href: "*endPoint*"
      }
    },
    hits: {...}
  ]
]
```

When the button at the bottom of the component is clicked it adds the newly fetched data to the data array with the previous fetch. I want to grab the href that's nested in the _links object from the last array inside the data array.

I am using a variable to grab it like:

```js
const nextPage = data[data.length - 1]._links.next.href
```

When I console log nextPage I get what I am expecting, but I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_links')` that's breaking the page.

What is the correct way to grab the href from the last array in the data array?

Comment: Your code looks correct.  `When I console log nextPage I get what I am expecting` then the code above is working.

Comment: It was only working occasionally for some reason. Like if I would edit something else in the code and save it would sometimes work, but most of the time it wasn't and I had no idea why.

Comment: Some other piece of code likely misbehaving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array of arrays of objects,

You can use `Array.prototype.flat()` to have 1 level of array and then `Array.prototype.at()` and get the last index of the array:

```js
const data = [
  [{_links: {}, hits:{}}],
  [{_links: {}, hits:{}}],
  [{
    _links: {
      next: {
        title: "Next",
        href: "*endPoint*"
      }
    },
    hits: {}
  }]
]

console.log(data.flat().at(-1)._links.next.href);
```

[Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)
[Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: That's exact what I needed, thanks!